# Unknown Command Line - R

Tags: r, command

I'm reading over some R code and came across this command

```
%&%
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdap/versions/2.2.5/topics/%25%26%25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the library, but you probably mean `qdap`.

From the `qdap` [documentation](http://%20https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdap/versions/2.2.5/topics/%25%26%25):

> ```
> qdap Chaining
>
> %&% - Chain qdap_dfs to qdap functions with a text.var argument. Saves typing of an explicit text.var argument and supplying a data.frame.
>
> Keywords
>     chain, chaining, pipe
>
> Usage
>
> qdap_df.object %&% qdap.fun
> ```

It could also be:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.2-8/topics/%25%26%25-methods

For example

```
set.seed(7)
L <- Matrix(rnorm(20) > 1,    4,5)
(N <- as(L, "nMatrix"))
D <- Matrix(round(rnorm(30)), 5,6) # -> values in -1:1 (for this seed)
L %&% D
stopifnot(identical(L %&% D, N %&% D),
          all(L %&% D == as((L %*% abs(D)) > 0, "sparseMatrix")))

## cross products , possibly with  boolArith = TRUE :
crossprod(N)     # -> sparse patter'n' (TRUE/FALSE : boolean arithmetic)
crossprod(N  +0) # -> numeric Matrix (with same "pattern")
stopifnot(all(crossprod(N) == t(N) %&% N),
          identical(crossprod(N), crossprod(N +0, boolArith=TRUE)),
          identical(crossprod(L), crossprod(N   , boolArith=FALSE)))
crossprod(D, boolArith =  TRUE) # pattern: "nsCMatrix"
crossprod(L, boolArith =  TRUE) #  ditto
crossprod(L, boolArith = FALSE) # numeric: "dsCMatrix"
```